# How can I overlap an element in the middle of 2 different columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a homepage right now, with a colored background as my section background, a background image as my 'about-left' div, which is located on the left half of this section, and content info on the right side of this same section. I made 6 width columns for each one of these, and that is working fine responsively.

I have a logo (.about-page-logo) that I want to put directly in the middle of the page, over the seam of where the 2 columns meet, and some writing that I want to put at the top of the page (.about-page-title), also going over the spot where the 2 columns meet. Also the page down arrow needs to run across the middle seam (.page-down-arrow). How do I go about doing that?

```
<section id="about">    

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="about-page-title">
      Anything that is seemingly impossible interests me.
    </div>

    <div class="about-page-logo">
      logo
    </div>

    <div class="page-down-arrow">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="about-left col-lg-6">
      </div>

      <div class="about-content col-lg-6">
        <div class="about-content-title">
          <h1>I'M JAY.</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="about-content-info">
          <p>Loren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsum
          <br /><br />

          Loren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsum
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="about-personal-info">
          <h4>Email:</h4>
          <h4>LinkedIn:</h4>
          <h4>GitHub:</h4>
          <h4>Angel List:</h4>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I suspect that we're going to need an image of what this is **supposed** to look like...it would make things much easier to understand.

Comment: just a jsfiddle of your current work would suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this simple raw example I made, I hope this could give you an idea.

HTML Markup

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="left">
        THIS IS LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        THIS IS RIGHT
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.left, .right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
.left { background-color: yellowgreen; }
.right { background-color: olive; }
.logo {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/omr83cqa/)

Comment: So are you saying I should drop the bootstrap columns for this section of the site? And just use floats instead?

Comment: No. In actuality bootstrap columns are floated, its still the same with my raw sample. You should focus on what I did on the .logo, I think thats the only thing you need. I just put everything so you can understand it as whole.

Comment: Ya I see now. I just tried it. I'm able to get the logo in the center, like you said. The margin part is done to make it responsive correct?

Comment: im not sure what margins you are talking about, but bootstrap margins are used so that the grid would present itself nicely, if theres no margins/paddings on it, texts for different columns would look like they are all connected.

Comment: If you are talking about the `margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;` No. I didn't put it there to make it responsive rather to make the logo at the center. Do note that the position of any element is based on its top left corner pixel not its very center. The `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` would place the top left corner of `.logo` on the very center of the screen. not its center. Thats when the negative value margins came up to even-out the position.

Comment: I meant the margin you put for the logo in the CSS. It wasn't perfectly responsive before I put that in.